Does PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo allow individual packets for changing a player's name?
I'm currently working on a plugin for my own Spigot server (1.8.x) and I'm encountering an issue with PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.
I'm trying to make the player name (above the head) display a different color depending on the player who is seeing it. Basically, I've tested different methods to achieve this, but none have worked.
The best method I've tried, in my opinion, is the following:
 (Into a PlayerJoinEvent Listener)

 EntityPlayer entityPlayer = ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle();
 GameProfile playerProfile = entityPlayer.getProfile();
 Field nameField = playerProfile.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
 nameField.setAccessible(true);
 nameField.set(playerProfile, ChatColor.RED + player.getName());

 PlayerConnection connection = ((CraftPlayer) Bukkit.getPlayer("HeartZone")).getHandle().playerConnection;
 connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, entityPlayer));
 connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, entityPlayer));

It partly works because I see my name in red, but every online player can see my name in red, and that's not what I'm looking for.
I've tried removing the following code:
PlayerConnection connection = ((CraftPlayer) Bukkit.getPlayer("HeartZone")).getHandle().playerConnection;
connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, entityPlayer));
connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, entityPlayer));

And the result is the same. So, is PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo really working and useful?
Finally, I tried adding:
nameField.set(playerProfile, ChatColor.stripColor(player.getName()));

But the color is normal (reseted) for all players seeing me, as if nameField.set(GameProfile, String) was calling packets by itself.
Edit : I've been searching and testing code for 2 days after publishing, please be kind.

The issue here comes from you are changing the player name, but the original player name. So everyone will got this new information.
The idea would be to make your own GameProfile object, or custom player data as showed in this post :

PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo info = new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo();
setInfo(info, EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER, info.new PlayerInfoData(prof, entity.ping, entity.playerInteractManager.getGameMode(), CraftChatMessage.fromString(name)[0]));



I'm going to try that and I let you know if it works, it seems so simple I'm surprised I didn't find it before. Thanks for your help !

It works fine, thanks for your help. I'll post a complete answer with my code working soon.

With the help of Elikill58 and based on his answer, I finally found a way to make this fonctionnality work as follows.
How to make a player name look different for each player : (tested in 1.8)
// First, you have to allow the player entity name field to be changed

Player target = *your way to get a Player*;
String originalName = target.getName();

EntityPlayer entityPlayer = ((CraftPlayer) target).getHandle();
GameProfile playerProfile = entityPlayer.getProfile();
Field nameField = playerProfile.getClass().getDeclaredField("name");
nameField.setAccessible(true);

// All the following code can be sent in a Queue (java.util)
// to avoid name issues if you have to send a lot of packets
// in a short time.

// Then, you can change the player's name situationally
// In my usage, I used the Factions plugin API to change the player name
// with the ally/enemy/neutral/truce color

String customName = *Player name with the modifications you like*;

// And for each player who needs to see the custom name :

connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(
  PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER, 
  entityPlayer
));
connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutEntityDestroy(entityPlayer.getId()));

nameField.set(playerProfile, customName);

connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo(
  PacketPlayOutPlayerInfo.EnumPlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER,
  entityPlayer
));
connection.sendPacket(new PacketPlayOutNamedEntitySpawn(entityPlayer));

// Finally, don't forget to reset the player's name to the default

nameField.set(playerProfile, originalName);

I hope this helps.
